# git log extension in VSCode throwing error ambiguous argument 'HEAD'

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-log, git-revision

One strange issue i am facing is git history extenstion in VSCode throwing me error that - ambiguous argument HEAD if i select a file and click on git history extension button to see the history on the file. 
But if i run the git command manually to check commits on that file, it works. Can you please help me on this. I even cannot uninstall reinstall git history from VSCode

When clicking '**Git: View History**' button at the top right corner of the screen , the error is -

```
git rev-list --full-history --count master --  (completed in 0.102s)
fatal: bad revision 'master'

git log --full-history --pretty=oneline --date-order --decorate=full --skip=0 --max-count=100 master --  (completed in 0.106s)
fatal: bad revision 'master'

git shortlog -e -s -n HEAD  (completed in 0.111s)
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]
```

But when i run the following git bash command , it gives me proper commits log-

```
git log <filename>
commit 9cd4423a53ef3737d8d43a2e19185eead51e103f (HEAD -> <branch1>, origin/<branch1>)
Author: XX <...>
Date:   Sat Jun 6 07:24:57 2020 +0530

    terminate protect value false modified

commit a37cce30dcb76d857fc44bd98601ac1ce2e567a3
```